# Twitter API question

Tags: xml, twitter

I have a question regarding Twitter API. I came across something called "Parameters and Values" in the API console here : http://dev.twitter.com/console. What can I put here ? I want to filter the response of public statuses to only those have the Hashtag #Give .. Can I do that from here ? What language should I use here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That part of the API Console is simply to allow you to pass various POST parameters to find outputs (most of these parameter options are documented in the "Methods" section in [the API documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/streaming_api)).

Filtering of tweets is related to the [statuses/filtering method/parameter combination](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/filter) and, thus, [the documentation](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/post/statuses/filter) will be your best help here (and you can test it out via the console)!